# for loops (R) within data frame; trying to get top 5 locations with corresponding number of people

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

first off:
Suppose I have a dataset that has variables like to_location_id, from_location_id gender, and age. now if i want to know overall the top 5 locations people like to visit i do this:

```
#most popular 5 locations to go to 
top<-as.data.frame(sort(table((mydata$to_location_id),decreasing = TRUE)[1:5])


> top

   sort(table(mydata$to_location_id), decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]

3                                                       18544

9                                                       18395

76                                                      15457

5                                                       14342

1                                                       13898
```

***this gives the most 5 popular locations to go to overall in the dataset**
 locations 3 , 9, 76, 5, and 1 
**similarly i can also get the most 5 popular locations to come form overall

Now suppose that there are 100 unique location id's (in both from and to location id's) I want to know for each location what are the top 5 popular to and the top 5 popular from locations given each location. i know i need a loop but i'm not sure how to do it. i have tried this (no luck):

```
for(i in unique(mydata$to_location_id)){
 as.data.frame(sort(table(mydata$to_location_id),decreasing = TRUE)[1:5])
}
```

Comment: What about something like `print(head(sort(table(mydata$from_location_id[mydata$to_location_id == i]), decreasing = TRUE)))` in your loop?

Comment: Can you please explain this more @user3380372? I don't quite get the question.